# How display data fetched from database on a jsp page using struts and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts, struts-1

I am trying to display data from my database to a Jsp page using Hibernate with struts 2. Although there is no error nothing gets displayed.I tried to find a solution from other posts but could not.
This the action class.

```
 public class ListeActeurAction  extends Action{

public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Action");

    ListeActeur ListeActeur= (ListeActeur) form;
            String query = "select nomActeur from Acteur " ;
            ListeActeur.setLis( HibernateUtil.ListeActeur(query, req)); 
    req.setAttribute("ListeActeur", ListeActeur.getLis()) ;
                    return mapping.findForward("s");
```

methode:HibernateUtil.ListeActeur(query, req)

```
 public   static List <Acteur> ListeActeur(String query,HttpServletRequest req){

System.out.print("hutil");
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
 Iterator results = session.createSQLQuery(query).list().iterator();
 List <Acteur> list = new ArrayList<Acteur>();


 while((results.hasNext()))
 {
     Acteur gg =new Acteur();
    //Object[] row = (Object[]) results.next();
    //gg.setActeurId((Integer)row[0]);
    gg.setNomActeur(( java.lang.String)results.next());

list.add(gg);
 }


req.getSession(true).setAttribute("ListeActeur", list);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
 HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close(); 
 return list;
```

}

```
<html:form action="Liste" >
  <table>
    <tr>  
      <logic:iterate  name="ListeActeur" property= "lis"  id="Acteur" >
        <td><b>Nom Acteur:<bean:write name="Acteur" property="nomActeur"/></b> <br></td>
        <td><b>Adresse IP :<bean:write name="Acteur" property="adresseIp"/></b> <br>  </td>
      </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
  </table>
</html:form>
```

struts-config

```
    <!DOCTYPE struts-config 
    PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.0//EN" 
     "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">
    <struts-config>

<form-beans type="org.apache.struts.action.ActionFormBean">
  <form-bean name="ListeActeur" type="mesForms.strust.ListeActeur"/>
</form-beans>
    <action-mappings >
   <action path="/Liste" 
    parameter="/vue/Invitation.jsp"
    name="ListeActeur"
    scope="session"
    validate="false"
    type="mesAction.struts.ListeActeurAction">  
    <forward name="s" path="/vue/Invitation.jsp" redirect="false" />
    </action>
   </action-mappings>

 </struts-config>
```

I dont understand what am i doing wrong,Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: I indented your code, but you overwrote my changes with your own edit. Indent your code, respect Java naming conventions, and everything will be clearer for everyone, including you. And post your real code. You don't even have a starting logic:iterate tag. If your code was indented, you wouldn't have missed that.

Comment: Im sorry but when i post my code they don't appeart.there is my page jsp :<html:form  action="Liste" > 
  <table>  
<logic:iterate  name="ListeActeur" property= "lis"  id="Acteur" >
<td><b>Nom Acteur:<bean:write name="Acteur" property="nomActeur"/></b> <br></td>
<td><b>Adresse IP :<bean:write name="Acteur" property="adresseIp"/></b> </b>  </td>
</tr>

Comment: Edit your code. Indent id. Add the JSP code inside your question. Code blocks should be indented by four spaces, and there is even a button that makes it for you: select your code, click it (it has curly braces as icon).

Comment: there is my code jsp in my question, sorry i'm new in the site and i can't pose à code i don't khnow why

Comment: I have indented your JSP code. The opening <td> should match with the closing </td>. Same for every other pair of opening and closing tags. Your code is completely wrong. Indent it, fix it, and post it back. And do the same with your Java code. If you don't indent your code, it will be an unreadable mess. For you and for your coworkers. Indentation helps finding errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777391/how-to-retrieve-the-data-from-the-database-and-display-it-on-a-jsp-using-struts i think my question is more clear here , please help meeeeeee

Comment: i close all the tag, I do not think that's the problem

Comment: You have a `</b>` without `<b>`. You have a `</tr>` without `<tr>`. You have a `<logic:iterate>` without `</logic:iterate>`. And your Java code is also a mess. And you post the same question twice. You won't get answers if you don't show a little effort when asking the question. If the question is unreadable, nobody will care to answer.

Comment: i have edit my code, it is good???

Comment: No, it's not, because you haven't indented it properly. I have done it for you, once again, and now it's obvious that the `</tr>` doesn't match the `<tr>`, and that the `</logic:iterate>` doesn't match `<logic:iterate>`.

Comment: thank you, but the same problem is here : display a blank page, i don't inderstand why ?help me please

Comment: Post the relevant sections of your struts-config file.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same attribute name thrice:

```
<form-bean name="ListeActeur" type="mesForms.strust.ListeActeur"/>
<action path="/Liste" name="ListeActeur" scope="session" ...
```

means that the Struts will store a bean of type `mesForms.strust.ListeActeur` in the session attribute `ListeActeur` when invoking the action `/Liste`.

In this action, you're doing

```
req.setAttribute("ListeActeur", ListeActeur.getLis());
```

So here, you're storing a `java.util.List` in the request attribute `ListeActeur`. This request attribute is completely unnecessary, since the same list is available already in the bean ListeActeur which is already stored in the session.

But wait, before doing that, the code which fetched some data from Hibernate decided to do

```
req.getSession(true).setAttribute("ListeActeur", list)
```

and to override what Struts stored in the session with the same `java.util.List`.

So, to resume, at the end of this action method call, you have

- an attribute `ListeActeur` of type `java.util.List` in the request
- an attribute `ListeActeur` of type `java.util.List` in the session, which is the same list as the one stored in the request.

And now the JSP is executed:

```
<html:form action="Liste" >
```

This line tells Struts to get the form bean of type associated to the Liste action from the session, or to create it and store it. It should normally be there already, but you replaced it with a java.util.List, so Struts removes your List from the session and replaces it by a brand new `mesForms.strust.ListeActeur`.

```
<logic:iterate name="ListeActeur" property= "lis"  id="Acteur" >
```

And now you try iterating through the collection stored in the property `lis` of the bean `ListeActeur`. I don't know exactly how Struts does here, but either it finds your `java.util.List` in the request, which doesn't have a `lis` property, or it finds the `ListeActeur` bean in the session, but since it's brand new, its `lis` property is an empty or null list.

Steps to fix this mess:

- Respect namng conventions: variables and attributes start with a lower-case letter. Form bean classes should be named SomethingForm, and action classes should be named SomethingAction. Form bean names in struts-config should be named somethingForm.
- form beans should almost never be stored in the session scope in the struts-config.xml. Store them in request scope.
- You should NEVER store a form bean in any scope yourself. Struts does it for you.
- The code whose responsibility is to get data from the database doesn't have to deal with request and session attributes. It takes arguments in parameters, and returns objects. Let your action deal with the request and session.
- Since you choose to store the result of the query in your form bean, no need to store it elsewhere. Struts stores your form bean in the request. You store the query result in the form bean. No need for anything else.
- Choose meaningful names for your properties. `lis` doesn't mean anything. If you have a list of Acteur, call it `acteurs`.

Here's how your action method should look like (and look how it's properly indented):

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, 
                             ActionForm actionForm,
                             HttpServletRequest request, 
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    ListeActeurForm form = (ListeActeurForm) actionForm;
    List<Acteur> acteurs = acteurService.findAll();
    form.setActeurs(acteurs); 
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

And here's how your JSP should look like (using the JSTL, since logic tags are deprecated for years):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name of the acteur</th>
            <th>IP address of the acteur</th>
        <tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%-- one row per acteur --%>
        <c:forEach var="acteur" items="${listeActeurForm.acteurs}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${acteur.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${acteur.ipAddress}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer , but how can i use jstl with strust1?

Comment: Like you would use JSTL without struts1. You put the JSTL jars in WEB-INF/lib, you declare the taglib at the top of your JSP, and you use the tags in the JSP. But you may keep using struts tags if you prefer. Just replace c:forEach with logic:iterate, and c:out with bean:write, et voilà.

Comment: I change the class action as you have offered me and I keep the same jsp, but still empty list

Comment: what is the difference between scopr "session" and scope "request"?

Comment: OMG, you really need to follow some tutorial about web development in general, and the servlet API in particular. The request represents a simple request made by the user to the server: a link click, a form submission. The session represents a kind of connection with a particular user. It starts from the moment the session is open (typically, when the user makes the first request to the application), and it ends after a timeout, once the user has not sent any request to the application for half an hour for example (or when the session is explicitely deleted at server-side).

Comment: In short, if you store some object in the session, it will stay there until the user leaves the application. You should only store things that must stay in the session from the beginning to the end: the user ID, its security permissions, things like that.